# Get the date of the first share for a URL from Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'd like to get the number of shares, the time of the first share, and the time the stats were updated for a given URL from the Facebook graph API. Currently, I'm using: `https://graph.facebook.com/?id=https://www.stackoverflow.com`, and this returns:

```
{
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 2808
   },
   "og_object": {
      "id": "10151023731873397",
      "title": "Stack Overflow",
      "type": "website",
      "updated_time": "2017-10-02T10:57:48+0000"
   },
   "id": "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
}
```

The problem here is that I don't know the time the first share happened (which I'm using as a proxy for when the article was created). My use case is determining how fresh a news article is.

Comment: i don´t think that´s possible with the api, but you could check for the share count with a cron job as soon as the article is online.

Comment: _"My use case is determining how fresh a news article is"_ - then find a proper way to do that - not abusing a third-party API in the process, that is absolutely not meant for this.